# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Tags: html, arrays, reactjs, typescript

here is my code snippet

```
      {animals.map((animal: Array<any>, i: number) => {
        return <span  id={i} className={index === i ? "animal active" : "animal"} onClick={handleAnimalSelect}></span>;
      })}
```

error

```
(JSX attribute) React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>.id?: string
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1760, 9): The expected type comes from property 'id' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>'
```

Comment: Try `key={i.toString()}`
Btw, it is bad idea to use array index as key. I'd say - very bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared `i` to be a `number` but the `id` must be a `string`. Change `id={i}` to `id={i.toString()}` and `key={i}` to `key={i.toString()}`.